# Is it possible to control switching the alphabet and numbers keyboards on iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, keyboard

I have a form which contains a lot of individual fields which contain numeric values. The issue I have is that on an iPad the on-screen keyboard is split between an alphabetic and numeric one like so: [image: iPad keyboard]

The issue is that when switching between each individual form field, the iPad reverts to the alphabetic keyboard which is not disastrous but definitely inconvenient for the end user. Is there anything I can do to tell iPad which keyboard to show for a specific input type or some other way of keeping the numeric keyboard for certain form elements?

I'm specifically referring to developing for the web and not iOS apps. I'm sceptical and so far Googling has not brought up any results but I wonder if there is an input type that iPad might recognise as numeric automatically.

Comment: Did you try with pattern attribute? `<input type='text' pattern='\d'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input type.  Instead of using a text input try one of the following to bring up the special keyboard (note:  this is not unique to the iPad).  This is going to be device-dependent and be supported depending on the device used.

```
<input type="number">
```

Shows the number pad

```
<input type="email">
```

Shows the text pad with the @ symbol

```
<input type="url">
```

Shows the text pad with the .com button (if available)

```
<input type="text">
```

Shows the standard text pad

Comment: Excellent, type="number" worked like a charm, almost can't believe I didn't know about it to begin with! Thanks!

Comment: No Problem.  If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer to help me out on here, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, just had to wait until SO let me!

Comment: No problem at all.  Let me know if there's anything else I can help you out with.

Comment: Please note, that type=number really means a number. A string of digits starting with 0 for example is not a number. So be careful here. Future versions of iOS will either remove such a value or stop the user from submitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 field types

Change the field type:

`<input type="text" name="SomeField">`

To:

`<input type="number" name="SomeField">`

This should make the iPad and phones default to the numeric input pad.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp